# Does DurandalJs support location.href="#page1"

Tags: durandal, durandal-2.0, durandal-navigation

I want to redirect to the previous page on click of a button , i am able to do this using location.href="#PrevPage" will it affect any durandalJs functionality

Answer (score 0):

You can update to use

router.Navigateback()